# How to make pages of tables?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am having a bit of hard time wording this right, so please don't be quick about dismissing the question.

```
<table>
    <tr id =1>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id =2>
        <td>col43</td>
        <td>col546</td>

    </tr>
    <tr id =3>
        <td>col143</td>
        <td>col1546</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id =4>
        <td>col434534</td>
        <td>col5463453</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id =5>
        <td>col1434533</td>
        <td>col1546345</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<style>

table,td{
    border: 2px solid #0e0d0d;
    text-align: left;
    height: 54px;
  }
</style>
<button>Prev</button><button>Next</button>
```

The display of the table should be in the format of 2 rows a page. What I mean is that when first loaded it only should show id = 2 and id = 3. And then when next is clicked it should show id =4 and id =5 only.

And when on the page showing id =4 and 5 I click prev it should go back to the view of id =2,3.

To summarize each view of the page can consist of a max upto 2 rows.

Any idea on how to do that.

P.S In my actual code I have to get the data from python and then render it into html.

Comment: So you need to implement pagination with two items dispayed per page, right? Is there requirement to use any specific js library like jquery, React or somthing else?

Comment: preferably JS, I am not familiar with jquery or react, but am open to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your HTML code you could write a small function, which hides all the rows of the table except the ones of the current "page" by setting their `display` style property to `none` or `table-row`. For this you don't have to assign IDs to your rows when using the JavaScript Table API:

```js
const itemsPerPage = 2;
let page = 0;

function showPage(index) {
  const table = document.getElementById('my-table');
  const rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
  if (index < 0) {
    page = 0;
  }
  else if (index > table.rows.length - itemsPerPage) {
    page = rows.length / itemsPerPage + 1;
  }
  else {
    page = index;
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (i >= page && i < page + itemsPerPage) {
      rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
    }
    else {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';    
    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  text-align: left;
  height: 54px;
}

table, td {
  border: 2px solid #0e0d0d;
}

table > tbody > tr {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body onload="showPage(0)">
    <table id="my-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
        </tr>    
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>col43</td>
          <td>col546</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>col143</td>
          <td>col1546</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>col434534</td>
          <td>col5463453</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>col1434533</td>
          <td>col1546345</td>
        </tr>    
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <button onclick="showPage(page - 1)">Prev</button>
    <button onclick="showPage(page + 1)">Next</button>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [jquery datatables](https://datatables.net/manual/) for that purpose. It's very lightwait and easy to use. Here is a working example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
         pagingType: "simple",
         pageLength: 2
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
<script rc="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brock Lee</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>Tampa</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://pypi.org/project/jinja-datatables/

Comment: The code works, but I add rows to the table dynamically using js, I notice that this function pulls the data from the document so not the data that is added in later. Is there a way to incorporate that?

Comment: Yes, you can use datatables to create tables from different datasources. This is just an example based on code you posted. Here is example of ajax datasource https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Comment: its more like I do this:

Answer (score 0):

```js
let max = 6
let prev_start = null

function next(){
  
  let next = null
  
  for(let row = 0; row < max + 1; row++){
    if($('#'+row).css('display') == 'table-row' || $('#'+row).css('display') == 'block'){
      next = row + 1
      prev_start = next - 2
    }
  }
  show(next)
}

function show(next){
  
  let prev_r_one = next-1
  let prev_r_two = next-2
  $('#'+prev_r_one).css('display', 'none')
  $('#'+prev_r_two).css('display', 'none')
  
  for(let row = next; row < next + 2; row++){
      $('#'+row).css('display','block')
  }
}

function prev(){

  for(let row = 1; row < max + 1; row++){ $('#'+row).css('display','none')  }
  
  if(prev_start <= 0){prev_start = 1}
  
  let row_x = prev_start
  let row_y = row_x + 1
 $('#'+row_x).css('display', 'block')
 $('#'+row_y).css('display', 'block')
  
  prev_start = row_x -2
}
```

```css
table,td{
    border: 2px solid #0e0d0d;
    text-align: left;
    height: 54px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr id =0>
        <th>col 1</th>
        <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id =1>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id =2>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id =3 style="display:none">
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id =4 style="display:none">
        <td>row 4</td>
        <td>row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id =5 style="display:none">
        <td>row 5</td>
        <td>row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id =6 style="display:none">
        <td>row 6</td>
        <td>row 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="prev()">Prev</button><button onclick="next()">Next</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.